# "help to fix ' error: unable to read property list from file: info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, gml

I added Admob Google extension in to my Game Maker 2 project, when I try to test it on xcode for iOS,  I am getting the error from xcode : unable to read property list from file: ...

- Tried to fiddle around with the build settings in Xcode for plist to make it XML/Binary and same as input but nothing helped.
- Made sure that the extensions in game maker have IOS enabled
- Tried to clean build folder
- Changed Locations: of Derived data to Relative
- Looked for similar problems on google and stack overflow, but nothing exactly with the same issue

Below is the code given by Gamemaker

```
if os_type == os_ios
    {
    ads_app_id = "ca-app-pub-4724502015965127~5126911475";
    banner_id = "ca-app-pub-4337965814269841/5893054134";
    interstitial_id = "ca-app-pub-4724502015965127/8852681295";
    rewarded_id = "ca-app-pub-4724502015965127/3717109960";
    }
else
    {
    ads_app_id = "ca-app-pub-4337965814269841~8766033395";
    banner_id = "ca-app-pub-4337965814269841/5893055122";
    interstitial_id = "ca-app-pub-4337965814269841/5893055258";
    rewarded_id = "ca-app-pub-4337965814269841/5893055399";
    }
GoogleMobileAds_Init(interstitial_id, ads_app_id);
GoogleMobileAds_LoadInterstitial();
interstitial_loaded = false;
```

error:

> unable to read property list from file:
>   /Users/faisalnaamani/GameMakerStudio2/iOS/GMS2IOS/Pixel_Bricks_iOS/Pixel_Bricks_iOS/Pixel_Bricks_iOS/Supporting
>   Files/Pixel_Bricks_iOS-Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 1.)

The error is happening at Build time

Comment: Is it possible you have another info.plist file somewhere in your project?

Comment: There is another one in a folder called tests and there the file is Info.plist, it is identical to the one in the other folder

Answer (score 1):

I opened the plist file with ATOM, the one generated by GameMaker Studio when I noticed xcode could not read it. I noticed a bit of code that was causing an error and when I deleted it xcode was able to build. The code is below:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>\n\r<dict>\n\r    
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>\n\r    <true/>\n\r    
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia</key>\n\r    <true/>\n\r    
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>\n\r    <true/>\n\r</dict>
```

But I am not sure how to fix it to make it look correct. I am afraid if I delete it somehow the code will not be correct. Does anyone have a solution? And how would I fix it from GameMaker.

Answer (score 1):

As Faisal suggested, the file cannot be read if it's malformed.

Trying to open the file with Xcode helped me find the problem: a syntax error. Xcode was very explicit about where the error might be: `at line 32`.

After fixing the error in *another IDE* I was able to open the file with Xcode and build/run my app.

[image: Xcode error]